# when add key-value pair to a hashMap, why Java makes hashMap's hashCode change?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashcode, hashset

If you look at java's hashCode method inside hashMap, you will find:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = 0;
    Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
        h += i.next().hashCode();
    return h;
}
```

So when you insert things into hashMap, hashMap's hashCode will change. Thus, if we insert an empty hashMap into hashSet, then insert something to this hashMap, then call `hashSet.contains(hashMap)`, it will return `false`. 
Why does Java allow such behavior? This will easily cause duplicate items in a hashSet.

Try run the following code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashSet<HashMap<Integer, String>> set = new HashSet<>();
        HashMap<Integer, String> b = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println("adding hashcode: " + b.hashCode() + "to set");
        set.add(b);
        b.put(8, "arsenal");
        for(HashMap<Integer, String> map: set){
            Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Finding b: " + set.contains(b));
        System.out.println(b.hashCode());

        set.add(b);

        for(HashMap<Integer, String> map: set){
            Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know *why*, or do you want to know *how to work around this*?

Comment: I want to know why HashMap's hashCode is dependent on its stored data.

Answer (score 4):

> Why Java allow such behavior?

Because keys are supposed to be invariant, according to their `equals()` implementation. If you mutate a key in such a way that comparisons by means of its `equals()` method are affected, then the behaviour of the map is unspecified.

And this is exactly what you're doing when you change your `HashMap` while it's an element of the `HashSet`, since `HashSet` is actually backed by a `HashMap`.

This is an excerpt of the [`Map` interface documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a map to contain itself as a key. While it is permissible for a map to contain itself as a value, extreme caution is advised: the equals and hashCode methods are no longer well defined on such a map.

If I were you, I wouldn't use a mutable map as the key of a structure that relies on the immutability of its elements.

Answer (score 0):

The [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) gaurantees there may be collisions. There are other `Map` implementations, including [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) which do not exhibit the behavior you describe. In the case of `LinkedHashMap` it is described in the Javadoc (in part) as a *hash table and linked list implementation of the `Map` interface, with predictable iteration order*.