# HashCode alteration upon insertion of data into hashMap

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashcode

I have an implementation of a hashMap.  When calling the get() function, which returns the associated value of the input key, if it exists, iterates through the map to see if it can find an entry with a key that are equivalent to the input and also share the same hashcode.  If so, it returns the associated value.

I learned that the error is occurring somewhere in a helper method branching from my put(Object K, Object V) function.

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    System.out.print("KEY at PUT IS " + key);
    if (key == null) {
        ...
        return null;
    }
    int hash = key.hashCode();
    int bucket = hash(hash, table.length);
    System.out.println("Key is " + key + "bucket is " + bucket + "hash is " + hash);
    ...

    add(hash, key, value, bucket);
    return null;
}
```

The relevant part of the helper function is as follows.

```
private void add(int hash, K key, V val, int bucket) {
    Entry<K, V> e = table[bucket];

    System.out.println("table[bucket] before adding a value is " + table[bucket]);
    System.out.println("key in ADD is " + key + "HASH in ADD " + hash);

    table[bucket] = new Entry<K, V>(key, val, e);
    size++;

    System.out.println(" table[bucket] is now " + table[bucket].key + " table[bucket] hash is now" + table[bucket].hashCode());

    ...
}
```

Now, if i create a new hashMap, x, and call x.put("foo", 2); the following is printed.

```
PUTTING 2
...
(we reach the add function)
table[bucket] before adding a value is null
Key in ADD is foo, HASH in ADD 101574
table[bucket] is now foo, table[bucket] hash is now 3149757
```

My assumption is that it has something to do with how I am inputting the new entry.  However, a new entry is simply instantiated with a key, value, and "next" item.  So, after a long time debugging I cannot understand how the hashCode changed from 101574 to 3149757.

I read this question to see that inserting data can alter a previous hashCode.

[when add key-value pair to a hashMap, why Java makes hashMap's hashCode change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556185/when-add-key-value-pair-to-a-hashmap-why-java-makes-hashmaps-hashcode-change)

However, i have seen several implementations where this does not appear to be an issue.
    Shouldn't this hashCode remain the same?

Comment: The hashcode didn't change.  You are taking the hashcodes of two different objects:  the key of type K, and table[bucket] of type Entry<K,V>.

Comment: And the question that you link doesn't say that the object you put into the HashMap changes hashcode, but rather that the **table** as a whole changes hashcode when you insert additional objects into it.

Comment: I understand. But shouldn't calling put("foo", 2) and followed by get("foo") return 2?  I noticed that performing these operations in JUnit and calling assertEquals(2, x.get("foo")), stated 2 was expected and null was returned. @JohnAngland

Comment: Ah, figured it out! In my get() function, I was comparing the hashcode of the next entry to the hashcode of the key.